# a youtube regex that works but needs improving

Tags: regex

I currently have this regex that works successfuly on plain text youtube links.

```
 /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
```

So it works on something like this -->

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y34jC4I1m70
```

Where it fails however is detecting a youtube link inside an  tag

```
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y34jC4I1m70'>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y34jC4I1m70</a>
```

Is there a way i can make it catch both?

Comment: Can you show us a code example of how you are using this regex?

Comment: As a general note, regex is a bad approach to markup languages. Use a parser instead, and look for links in the right places.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading ^. 
However I am wondering the .* should work in this case. But why you need a . inside the word youtube?

Comment: Somehow, your regex was working fine in my tests for both the input strings.